# how to avoid too fast requests made by an user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, httprequest

I am working on asp.net mvc4. I want to check how many requests are made by a user per second. if this number is greater than any specified number, user will be blocked for some time. Please provide an idea to implement it. Is this helpful for checking bot attacks? if not how it can be achieved?
Thank you.

Comment: You should provide more infos about your web-app.
What does it do?
How does it track users?
The helpfulness depends on what your app is supposed to do, and how / what checks are performed so it's kind of impossible to answer beforehand.

Comment: I have to apply it in an ERP project in which user logs in and access different services. I want to track user so that he could not make too many requests per unit time or the services are not being hit by another program(DoS Attack).

Answer (score 0):

You need a throttle mechanism. I recommend checking out [the Reactive extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229400%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and the throttle method to implement it.

EDIT: in fact a throttle mechanism will help deter the problem you encounter by ensuring that no more than x calls per unit of time are processed. This could help you prevent overloading your system but i don't know if it could help monitor the frequency of messages. I think the frequency of messages should happen before the throttling: monitor and resist potential abuse